# Mongoose sort by child value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a parent and child schema that looks like:

```
schedule = Schema ({
    from: Date,
    to: Date
});

content = Schema ({
    schedule: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "schedule" }
    name: String
});
```

My question is, how do I query Mongoose to return "all content, sorted by schedule.from date"?

Comment: Can you show me how the data is stored in the MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to sort in two steps on the client, or store the date fields you want to sort on as embedded fields within the `content` object.

You're trying to do a collection join by using data from two collections. As MongoDB doesn't support a join, you'd need to populate the `schedule` field and then do a sort locally on the client. If you have very many documents, or want to do paging of data, this of course won't work.

The most efficient means would be to store the date fields in the `content` model so that you can perform sorting directly from a single document and collection, without the need of a join. While that may cause other issues with the schema design that you'd like to have, you may find this is the most efficient. The benefit of this denormalization process is that you can do sorting, filtering, etc. very easily and efficiently (especially if you've indexed the date fields for example).

```
schedule = Schema ({
    from: Date,
    to: Date
};

content = Schema ({
    schedule: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "schedule" },
    schedule_data: { 
        from: Date,
        to: Date
    },
    name: String
});
```

You could leave the `schedule` field in the `content` schema if you wanted to be able to quickly locate and update `content` documents (or if there were other less used or not needed for sorting/filtering).

Comment: Seems like I may have to do something like this, it's not even remotely efficient, but works.  I may just embed the schedule schema as a doc vs using the reference.

Comment: Using MongoDB requires a different way of thinking, especially if you're accustomed to relational models.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you don't need a reference from one collection to another simply to store `schedule.from` & `schedule.to`.

Try the following :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
console.log('Mongoose connected to MongoDB\n');  
content_sch = Schema ({
        schedule: {
          from: Date,
          to: Date
    },
    name: String
});
var content = mongoose.model('content', content_sch);
         contentObj = new content();
         contentObj.schedule.from = Date.now();
         contentObj.schedule.to = Date.now();
         contentObj.name = 'Ryan Rife';  
         contentObj.save();
         //Sorting; -1 to specify an ascending or 1 descending sort respectively
         content.find({}).sort({'schedule.from': -1}).exec(function(err,contentDocs){
            console.log(contentDocs);
        });
});
```

You can do sorting in many ways another one is as follows which you could try:

```
content.find({}, null, {sort: {schedule.from: -1}}, function(err, contentDocs) {
  //console.log(contentDocs);
});
```

Check [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) for more [info](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort)

---

> When to go for references to documents in other collections?

There are no joins in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections (schema). Only then you need to use the `ObjectId` which refers to another `schema` and from that `schema` back to the parent.
Example:

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }] //Here is a link to child Schema 'Story'
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' }, //Field which again refers to parent schema 'Person'
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }] //Array which again refers to parent schema 'Person'
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

For more info check this [mongoose populate docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

---

Comment: This won't work because `schedule` is just an ObjectId in `content`, not an embedded doc.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Thanks.. I didn't notice that `Schema.ObjectId` I saw only question **sorted by schedule.from date**

Comment: It's also not valid JavaScript as written (`{schedule.from: -1}`).

Comment: I thought if I did a db.content.find({}).populate("schedule").sort({"schedule.from":-1}
).exec() it would work, but apparently the sort fires before the populate???